# How to identify which records were not updated after executing an update query in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update 100 records in oracle through the following update statement, but when I execute it, it says 90 records updated, whereas I have 100 records in the where clause.

Now how to identify which 10 records (codes) are not updated out of 100 in oracle?

In the following statement, I want to know the code names which were not updated? is there any simple trick to know?

update table1 a set a.column1='Yes'
where a.column2 in ('code1','code2','code3','code4',........,'code100');

Comment: Where is the list of codes coming from? Are you having to type that in, or are they stored in another table?

Comment: I'm wondering if you couldn't inspect the NOW_SCN value in the flashback data to see which bits in a table didn't share a specific system change number...

Comment: Do you even know for a fact that all 100 codes are actually present in the table?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith (and Ed) - I think they're looking for values from the `IN()` clause that don't exist in the table; rather than rows in the table that were not updated. But I may be wrong *8-) Perhaps Saurabh can clarify?

Comment: Thank you @AlexPoole, I will try your advice & let you know.  Actually, we have a table & its related view. I am trying to update the oracle view.  These codes are coming from a table1.   update view_table1 a set a.column1='Yes' where a.column2 in ('code1','code2','code3','code4',........,'code100');

Answer (score 2):

You can't really directly from the update; but you could use the same list of values (assuming it's a hard-coded list, not coming from a table) as a collection, and then look for values in the collection that are not in the table:

```
select *
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('code1','code2','code3','code4',........,'code100')) t
where not exists (
  select null
  from table1 a
  where a.column2 = t.column_value
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c3909413622e07ae16216c144adb007d) with a smaller set to demonstrate the idea.

You could modify your update to only update rows which are not already 'Yes'; and if you did that then you could either look for collection values that don't exist at all, or those which exist but don't need to be updated -  in that case, before you actually run the update, of course. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf51715b89bb1fefdca2b7e9a5048bf5).

[odcivarchar2list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/addci/extensibility-constants-types-and-mappings.html#GUID-4DC91855-BEF3-4D27-827E-147C74F127A2) is a built-in collection type, but you could use your own.

If you already have the values in a collection or table you can use that directly, both for this query and for the update.